# How to decrease the points border line width in gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

I'm trying to plot 100k points in a scatter plot. I couldn't distinguish between the points as the line width around the points is too big. Is there any way to remove this line or decrease the width of the line?

```
plot(x=A, 
     y=C, 
     Geom.point, 
     Theme(panel_fill=color("black"), 
           default_point_size=2pt, 
           default_color=color("red")));
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `highlight_width=0pt` (found [here](http://gadflyjl.org/themes.html)):

```
N = 10^4
A = rand(N)
B = rand(N)

plot(x = A, 
     y = B, 
     Geom.point, 
     Theme(panel_fill = colorant"black", 
           default_point_size = 2pt, 
           default_color = colorant"red",
           highlight_width = 0pt)
     )
```